# Small 'o' with macron (overbar) in html?

Tags: html

It seems like UTF-8 is missing the macron-over-o character. Am I alone in wanting this? In my mind it is a distinctive way of emphasizing the 'owe' sound in my web site title which is like Phoflot. The closest I can come in html is to put the 'o' in a span with text-decoration: overline, but the overbar floats way above the 'o', above the P,f,l letters.

Comment: ... really? so what is [this](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=o+macron)? Please, learn googling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't show any research efforts prior to ask.

Comment: I looked at UTF-8 codes by implication, and I showed I tried stuff. The fact I didn't find it doesn't disqualify my effort. Maybe someone else will have trouble figuring it out. It wasn't with the O's where I'd have expected it.

Comment: Reading the reason for the off-topic on-hold, I wonder whether the people applying it have even read what the reason says? I'm just defending the semi-aware user who thinks that all accented O's would be together, in keeping this alive.

Comment: `It seems like UTF-8 is missing the macron-over-o character.` is this a **programming** question? And I also posted a link which demonstrates you that you are **wrong**. Enough said.

Answer (score 2):

The unicode point for ō is [U+014D](http://graphemica.com/%C5%8D). You should be able to use `&#333;` or `&#x014D;`.

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions display the same in my blown-up Courier btw.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Unicode combining character U+0304 (#772 in HTML) with ordinary 'o' letter: `o&#772;`

Comment: Why not? The author of the question wanted to know a way to create an 'o with macron' character, which I provided.

Comment: It works, thanks! My uprate doesn't display due to my junior status.